# Java/Android. int = text?

Tags: java, android, database, postgresql

I've come into a strange error but I don't get it why it comes up. Basically, I am using a SELECT query to take some data from the database and it generates me an error.
The error is related to "WHERE traseu = " + traseu + ";". The column traseu in my PostgreSQL database is of type 'text';

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            String traseu = values[0];
            String sql = "SELECT id, ST_x(geom) AS x, ST_y(geom) AS y, tip AS tr, traseu, denumire, adresa, poza FROM modul WHERE traseu = " + traseu + ";";
```

It gives me the following error:

```
01-08 15:30:05.435  23635-23635/com.example.nsomething E/com.example.nsomething.main.Harta﹕ query failed to execute: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text = integer
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Position: 112
```

Any hints.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and read this http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not concatenate user supplied values into SQL text**.

This is dangerous and wrong:

```
String sql = "SELECT ... WHERE traseu = " + traseu + ";";
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                        Bad, don't do this
```

It's not actively dangerous for an integer, but it's still a terrible habit. Don't do it.

Instead you should [use parameterised statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

```
String sql = "SELECT ... WHERE traseu = ?;";

PreparedStatement st = conn.createPrepared(sql);
st.setInt(1, traseu);
```

See:

- http://bobby-tables.com
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Agreed, I was tired and had a pretty bad cold and didn't pay attention to a simple SQL query, totally forgot about SQL Injection, thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the parameter in single quotes.

eg:

...WHERE traseu = '" + traseu + "';"

Comment: Wow, that's what happens when you're tired and you're not paying enough attention. Thank you, I'll mark your answer as the one I was looking for.

Comment: Nononono! Please don't tell people to do this! It's safe in this case, with an int, but then they'll do it with strings and Bobby Tables will get sad. http://bobby-tables.com/ .